# Items in UItableViewCell gets displayed multiple times

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` with custom class and I have a xib for that custom class. Now I am registering nib in the `viewDidLoad` of the main class.

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TCellID")
```

Now in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am doing like this to get the cell rendered

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TCell
cell.bView.addTag(#SOMEITEM)
```

I am using library [here](https://github.com/xhacker/TagListView) to add tags

```
return cell
```

The cell is rendered correctly as I want, But the problem is that when I scroll the tableView up and down the #SOMEITEM is added again and again as I scroll up and down.

I think the problem is the rendering of the cell in the tableView. I tried putting breakpoint in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it is called everytime I scroll and that cell is shown. But I cannot figure out the exact problem. I searched and did not find a solution. I am working in swift

Hope you understand the problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is SOMETIME view contains ?

Comment: @BharathVankireddy updated the code

Comment: @FOOO is pull refresh happening?

Comment: @ksa_coder no there is no pull to refresh

Comment: @FOOO what is #SOMEITEM?

Comment: Could you add your full code for cellFirRowAtIndexPath?  What you have shown does the same thing for every cell ...

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are adding the tag each time the tableView asks you to configure the cell (whenever a new cell is about to appear on the screen).

Fix it by first removing all tags, and then adding the tags you want:

```
cell.bView.removeAllTags() // Or equivalent method.
cell.bView.addTag(#SOMEITEM)
```

Comment: is there any other way in which cell is rendered only once because once the cell is shown it does not changes and removing and adding every time seems lot of work. I am using this cell only one time.

Comment: This is how a UITableView works. Once it seems the cell no longer needed (i.e. When it is scrolled off screen) it needs to be rebuilt before it can be used again.

Comment: will the above code slow the scrolling? and what if I use a variable to save the cell and return that variable if that variable is not empty?

Comment: It should not slow scrolling, unless the removeAllTags() method is doing something funky. Using a bool will make your code more prone to bugs (especially if you start adding more cells).

Comment: I found some answer using if(cell==nil) in objective-C will this help?

Comment: You're fighting against how the API is intended to be used. Yes, that will have the effect you want, but what if the tag changes? You'll call reloadData, and the cell won't change its tag. Are there performance issues if you try the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You can override "prepareForReuse" in your custom UITableViewCell and add codes like Mark said.
`super.prepareForReuse()
bView.removeAllTags() // Or equivalent method.`

Comment: This looks like a more proper way of doing it.